# $.post not executing at certain places in code

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a snippet of code that calls $.post:

```
   1. console.log("at .post");
   2.  $.post('loadData.php',{fileName : 'box1.xml'}, function(xml) {
   3.                           $('#Status2').append(xml);
   4.                       debugger;
   5.                         }  
   6.       );
```

loadData.php on the server reads the fileName, 'box1.xml' and returns the contents as the data 'xml.' xml is appended to a status area so I can see the data and any complaints that loadData.php makes. Seeing
this in #Status2 tells me that the call was executed.

I can paste lines 1-6 at numerous places throughout my code and it works fine, but it doesn't run when it's placed in the each loop below:

```
$("#canvas .active[target]").each(function() {
    /******************** TEST   Doesn't work here*****************/
        console.log("at .post");
        $.post('loadData.php',{fileName : 'box1.xml'}, function(xml) {
                       $('#galleryStatus2').append(xml);
                       debugger;
                }  
                 );
       /***************************************/
```

The .post snippet code has nothing to do with the things jQuery is looking for here. The .post code is an independent piece of code that should run anywhere , it seems.

Does anyone know what I'm fighting here.  It seems to be related to being in an each-loop.

Thanks

Comment: Have you validated that your each selector `$("#canvas .active[target]")` is working as expected?  Do you see the console log within the loop?

Comment: `$("#canvas .active[target]")` may be empty list

Comment: ajax is asynchronous, so realize that the `$.post` will be called in rapid succession, while the response may come back in any order.

Comment: I see the console log so I know there's at least one member in the set.

Comment: How do I write a jsfiddle that makes an ajax .post() call to a php file on my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.post is asynchronous as has been stated in the comments but even then you are calling $.post to your server multiple times without having changed any of the parameters of it.

This means you are queuing up multiple duplicate ajax requests to your server which may return different responses depending on when they are processed. This will result in inexplicable results in some cases.

to simplify your current code you could do

```
$.post('loadData.php',{fileName : 'box1.xml'}, function(xml) {
        for(var i = 0; i < $("#canvas .active[target]").length; i++){
            $('#galleryStatus2').append(xml);
            debugger;
        }
    }  
);
```

This will call the php script once and then populate $('#galleryStatus2') with the xml as many times as there are $("#canvas .active[target]") elements. Why you would want to do this im not sure but this is a cleaner way to do what is already in your code.

If you are trying to pass information about the elements $("#canvas .active[target]") to the php script you can do something like

```
var ids = []
$("#canvas .active[target]").each(function(){
    ids.push($(this).prop('id'));
});

$.post('loadData.php',{fileName : 'box1.xml', ids: ids}, function(xml) {
        $('#galleryStatus2').append(xml);
        debugger;
    }  
);
```

and then have your php script handle batches of ids rather than 1 at a time and return xml for the entire set.

Comment: I don't mean to call $.post multiple times with the same parameters. How did you conclude that I was doing that? After studying the situation more for several hours,  I do suspect that the asynchronous character of Ajax is at the bottom of my troubles. After I launch the $.post my code continues on to a place where it issues a canvas.load(), long before the earlier .post finishes. So I have both of these on the wire at the same time.  I need to wait, I think, for the $.post to complete before doing any more Ajax. How do people normally synchronize multiple Ajax calls?  Thanks.

Comment: the $.post you are calling for each element in `$("#canvas .active[target]")` has exactly the same post parameters `{fileName : 'box1.xml'}` and exactly the same callback function which does `$('#galleryStatus2').append(xml);` but as i have mentioned if you are sending all those ajax calls at the same time it is a lot better to construct you ajax call in such a way that you only need 1 call

Comment: 'Sorry about that.  I simplified the code during debug to just use one value.  The actual code sets fileName based on the current element in the wrapped set, so it's different each time.  I solved this question by handling multiple ajax calls correctly with $.when.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290470/waiting-for-multiple-ajax-calls/18290536#18290536