# Waiting for multiple Ajax calls

Tags: jquery

I have an each-loop, below, that goes through div#canvas (nothing to do with HTML5's canvas) looking for elements that have to be loaded. Basically, if an element has a target attribute (line 1) and the target pointed to (target$) is not in div#canvas (line 6) an Ajax $.post request is launched (line 7) to bring the missing target in from the server and prepend it to div#canvas.

```
$("#canvas .active[target]").each(function() { 
    this$ = $(this);
    targetName = this$.attr('target'); 
    target$ = $('div[name=' + targetName + ']');

    if (target$.length == 0) {
        $.post('loadData.php', { fileName : targetName + '.xml' },function(xml) {  
            canvasData$ = $(xml).find("canvasData");  
            $('#canvas').prepend(canvasData$);      
        });
    }
});
```

When all of these missing targets have been loaded I want to issue an Ajax request to send all of `div#canvas` to the server.  That call looks like this:

```
Status$.load('writePage.php', { 
    pageName: pageName, 
    seg1: seg1, 
    canvas: canvasOuterHTML,
    seg2: seg2
});
```

Could someone suggest the best way to hold off the final call to `writePage` until all of the missing target reads have completed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $.when

```
var array = [];
$("#canvas .active[target]").each(function() { 
    this$ = $(this);
    targetName = this$.attr('target'); 
    target$ = $('div[name=' + targetName + ']');

    if (target$.length == 0) {
        var ajax = $.post('loadData.php', { fileName : targetName + '.xml' },function(xml) {  
            canvasData$ = $(xml).find("canvasData");  
            $('#canvas').prepend(canvasData$);      
        });
        array.push(ajax)
    }
});
$.when.apply($, array).done(function(){
    //do something
})
```

Comment: Wow! Nothing teaches you a new concept like seeing it solve a problem you were  working on. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by pushing the returned deferreds into an array and using `$.when` :

```
var xhrs = [];

$("#canvas .active[target]").each(function() { 
    var targetName = this.getAttribute('target'),
        target     = $('div[name="' + targetName + '"]');

    if (!target.length) {
        var xhr = $.post('loadData.php', { fileName : targetName + '.xml' },function(xml) {  
            var canvasData = $(xml).find("canvasData");  
            $('#canvas').prepend(canvasData);
        });
        xhrs.push(xhr)
    }
});   

$.when.apply($, xhrs).then(function() {
    // do something when all request have completed
});
```